# Flex order not working on unordered list

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying out flex on a blog archive page, listing the last 8 entries per page with a sidebar as one of the flex items - 9 items in total. The sidebar shows first in the normal flex order but i'd like it to show third (as sidebars normally do). Trying any `order` number on the sidebar item doesn't move it about within the list

https://jsfiddle.net/oliver_p/2v3duxy4/2/

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.list-item:first-child {
  order: 2;
}

.list-content-blog {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-content-blog .list-content-holder {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content-blog">

      <div class="list-image-holder">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="#">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-content-holder">
        <p class="post-meta-date"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> 5 March 2018</p>
        <h2 style=""><a href="#">Blog Title</a></h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content-blog">

      <div class="list-image-holder">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="#">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-content-holder">
        <p class="post-meta-date"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> 10 March 2018</p>
        <h2 style=""><a href="#">Blog Title</a></h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content-blog">

      <div class="list-image-holder">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="#">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-content-holder">
        <p class="post-meta-date"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> 15 March 2018</p>
        <h2 style=""><a href="#">Blog Title</a></h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: elaborate your question what exactly you want.

Comment: Because the parent ul is not displayed as flex.

Comment: Add display: flex; on ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you added (.list) class in your css but you forget to add class in your html,

exp. `<ul class="list">`

Comment: Apologies, copy and past issue into the fiddle, now updated and it works in the demo. I appear though to have some other extraneous CSS rules as it's not working on the demo site (which I cant post alink to currently)

Answer (score 0):

You tried it with `.list` that does not exist in your html(`class-"list"`) so try ul

```
 ul{
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

or add `class-"list"` to `ul` :
**HTML:**

```
<ul class-"list">
```

**CSS:**

```
   .list{
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

You've got:

```css
html * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 33.33333%;    
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.list-item:first-child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="list-item">
      1
 </li>
 <li class="list-item">
      2
 </li>
 <li class="list-item">
      3
 </li>
</ul>
```

...so you refer to the ul element by class that you have not applied.

Add class to the ul element and it will work:

```css
html * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 33.33333%;    
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.list-item:first-child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li class="list-item">
 1
</li>
<li class="list-item">
 2
</li>
<li class="list-item">
 3
</li>
</ul>
```